# What is the range of $f(x)= \lvert \cos(x) - \sin(x) \lvert$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I know that $ 0 \leq  \lvert \cos(x) - \sin(x) \lvert $ but I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: The  question originally defined $f(x, y) = \lvert \cos(x) - \sin(x) \lvert$, that was edited by @RobertZ to $f(x, y) = \lvert \cos(x) - \sin(y) \lvert$. I wonder if you actually meant $f(x) = \lvert \cos(x) - \sin(x) \lvert$ ?

Comment: @andrew Which function are you interested in? One or two variables? Sorry for the mess!

Comment: i modified my function

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

**Original problem - Range of $f(x)=|\cos x - \sin x|$**

Recall that $$f(x)=\cos x - \sin x=\sqrt 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}4 -x \right)=\sqrt2\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right)$$

or as an alternative by

$$f'(x)=-\sin x -\cos x = -\cos x\left(\tan x+1\right)=0 \implies x=\frac{\pi}4+k\pi$$

**New problem**

Let consider $f(x,y)=\sin x - \cos y$

- $f_x=\cos x=0$
- $f_y=\sin y=0$

then critical points are

- $x=\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$
- $y=k\pi$

then determine max and min.

Comment: or $$\sqrt2\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks! I add also that :)

Comment: @MartinRAh ok the first version was $f(x)=|\sin x + \cos x|$, you are right! There was some confusion with that, I fix.

Comment: I'm sorry but $f(x)=\cos x - \sin x=\sqrt 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}4 -\frac{x}{\sqrt 2} \right)$ ??

Comment: You can check by  $\sin(a-b)=\sin a \cos b-\sin b \cos a$ that $\sqrt 2 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}4 -x \right)= \cos x - \sin x$

Comment: @andrew Refer also to [Linear Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\cos x-1\cdot\sin x=\cos x-\tan\dfrac{\pi}{4}\cdot\sin x=\dfrac{\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}{\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

**After Edit:**
$$0\leq|\cos x-\sin y|\leq|\cos x|+|\sin y|=2$$

Comment: @xpaul the second one is about the two-variables function $f(x,y)=|\cos x-\sin y|$. See edit history!

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=| \cos x- \sin x|$, then $g(x):=f(x)^2=1-\sin (2x)$. We have $0 \le g(x) \le 2$ , $g(-\frac{\pi}{4})=2$ and $g(\frac{\pi}{4})=0$. Since $g$ is continuous, we get $g( \mathbb R)=[0,2]$, thus $f(  \mathbb R)=[0, \sqrt{2}].$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that$$f({\pi\over 4})=0$$and$$f(-{\pi\over 4})=\sqrt 2$$